# Angularjs fullcalendar drag drop - get value of dropped object

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angularjs-3rd-party

I am dropping an external object into [angular-ui-calendar](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar) using [angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop).

The external object is coming from this list:

```
<div class="fc-event" data-drag="true"
     jqyoui-draggable="{animate:true}"
     ng-model="test_object"
     ng-repeat="test_object in test_objects">
  Draggable - {{ test_object.name }} 
</div>
```

The fullcalendar is set up with:

```
<div id="ApptsCalendar" calendar="ApptsCalendar"
     ui-calendar="calendarOptions.calendar"
     ng-model="eventSources" data-drop="true"
     jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true, onDrop: 'drop_function'}"
     data-jqyoui-options>
</div>
```

When dropped, I can process that event using fullcalendar 'drop' method with:

```
$scope.calendarOptions = {
    calendar: {
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        drop: function(date,jsEvent,ui,resourceId){
            console.log("Dropped from calendarOptions")
            console.log(resourceId);
            $scope.eventSources[0].push({
                id:5,
                title: 'dropped event (fake)',
                start:  date
            });     
        }
    }
};
```

or from the angular-dragdrop 'onDrop' callback to call a 'drop' function:

```
jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true, onDrop: 'drop'}"
```

Both can trigger when I want, but neither seem to have the two pieces I need. I need to have the object value being dropped (defined in ng-model) and the date being dropped into.

Basically, I want to push the event to the the eventSources with:

```
$scope.eventSources[0].push({
    id:5,
    title: '...name of object...',
    start:  '...date of target dropped on...'
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fj858Htb2FRUg5h1pucP?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one of the things you wanted is already there. It's `date` on which the event is dropped. You get it from the first argument of the `drop` function. It's a `moment` object ([according to the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/drop)) so you might want to use `.toDate()` in order to get the JS `Date` object.

The other thing is the value of the event which got dropped. According to the same docs page, the DOM object of the event is accessible using `this` inside drop function.

Now, this is a bit unconventional way (I don't see many choices here), what you can do is, with the `ng-repeat` iterating over event objects, you can keep an attribute  with value from each object which can later be accessed inside the drop function. For example, see how I added `customEventName="{{test_object.name}}"` in here:

```
<div class="fc-event tech_draggable" data-drag="true" id="{{test_object.name}}" 
     customEventName="{{test_object.name}}" jqyoui-draggable="{animate:true}" 
     ng-model="test_object" ng-repeat="test_object in test_objects" ...>
    Draggable - {{ test_object.name }}
</div>
```

Then, in the drop function, that can be accessed using `this.getAttribute('customEventName')` like this:

```
$scope.calendarOptions = {
  calendar: {
    editable: true,
    droppable: true,
    drop: function(momentDate, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
      console.log(momentDate.toDate()) // gives JS Date object
      console.log(this.getAttribute('customEventName')); // gives event2/event3 etc.
      //... more
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my plunker example. Using customEventName attribute is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to make an attribute with a string representing the scope variable name:

```
<div ng-repeat="test_object in test_objects">
  <div class="fc-event tech_draggable" 
       data-drag="true" 
       jqyoui-draggable="{animate:true}" 
       ng-repeat="test_object in test_objects" 
       style="margin-bottom:1px;" 
       data-jqyoui-options="{helper: 'clone'}"
       scope-data-name="test_objects[{{$index}}]"
   >
    Draggable - {{ test_object.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

And using [$scope.$eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) to get the actual object:

```
$scope.calendarOptions = {
    calendar: {
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        drop: function(date,jsEvent,ui,resourceId){
            var scopeDataName = this.getAttribute('scope-data-name');
            var data = $scope.$eval(scopeDataName);
            $scope.eventSources[1].push({ 
                id: $scope.eventSources[0].length, 
                title: `${data.name} ${data.description}`,
                start: date
            }); 
        }
    }
};
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/33wubkNzLOiNdUdvatTM?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I think fullcalendar has the solution already.

I can use data-event attribute in the element:

```
data-event='{"title":"{{ test_object.name }}"}'
```

With that, there is no need to even have a 'drop' function... fullcalendar natively supports drag and drop.

I can then optionally use eventReceive to handle a drop from an external resource and use eventDrop to handle an internal event move.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fj858Htb2FRUg5h1pucP?p=preview